# new array from old array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write method getYoungestFemale.

Main:

```
Person[] person ={new Person("Bolton", 1992),new Person("Stark", 1973),new Person("Lannister",1962), new Person("Sansa", 2001), new Person("Arya", 1995), new Person("Olenna", 1938)};

Person.getYoungestFemale(pers);
```

end Person.java

```
static Person[] getYoungestFemale(Person[] a){

   int z=a[0].birth;
   int x = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
      String name=a[i].name;
      char temp = name.charAt(name.length()-1);
      String s = Character.toString(temp);

      if(s.equals("a")){
         if(a[i].birth>z){
            x = i;
         }
      }
    }

    System.out.print(a[x].name+" - "+a[x].birth);
    return a;
}
```

but it's give me strange result. `a.[x].name` is good (i'm really don't know why, it should be wrong too), birth and x index is wrong.

I think it's becase i compare birth data with int z, what is the yangest person in group, but it's man and he is yangest then the yangest women. I think I need to create second arr, only with woomen, and int z should be the first of women. And I don't know how to do it...

And my second question is, why a[x].name is good, and give me the yangest women in this group?

Comment: Can you ident your code to make it readable?

Comment: You declared as pers and then you pass as person.. is normal?

Comment: Well one issue is `z` (i.e. `birthYear`, consider renaming) is only set once at the beginning of the method. I'd image you want to set `z` in the if-block `if(a[i].birth<z)` (note I also think you want to flip the inequality if you're looking for the youngest person).

Comment: In the Person class you created you need a field for the sex of the person it represents.  If you do not have such a field then there is not way to reliably distinguish males from females.

Comment: Isn't Sansa older than Arya?

Comment: @TDG Aren't the first ones family names and the last ones first names?

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes they are...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to update your z and not use always the same.

I also did some optimization, in fact you can just track your index, try this:

```
static Person[] getYoungestFemale(Person[] a){

   int youngest = 0;

   for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){

     if(a[i].name.charAt(a[i].name.length()-1) == 'a')
       if(a[i].birth>a[youngest].bith){
          youngest = i;
       }
   }

  System.out.print(a[youngest].name+" - "+a[youngest].birth);
  return a;   // Are you shure to return all 'a'?
}
```

---

### Hint:

If you need to check for male and female; check for the last character isn't a good idea.
Maybe you can just add a:

```
boolean isMale; // true for male, false for female
```

to your class `Person`.

---

**OBS:**

Are you assuming that exist at least 1 young girl!?

Comment: `boolean isMale/isFemale` looks more clear. In any case, IMHO `boolean` is not the right data type to use for that. Probably an `enum` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @m0skit0 thanks, I appreciate isMale; So I edited my answer.

Comment: yes gender/sex should be initialised in Person class

Comment: @jsurf sorry I don't get your comment. Is just an affermation?

Comment: @jsurf yeah ok, maybe for me was implicit.. But it isn't thanks =)

Comment: ok, I corrected this mistakes, and I tryed your solutions, but unfortunately I sill have Arya - 2001,and  it should be Arya - 1995. And this is really strange....

Comment: @FKa if `a[youngest].birth` prints: `2001` it is beacuse there is 2001... Your error is in another part of your code.... Moreover as I told: You declared as `person` and then you pass as `pers` .. is normal? IMHO you're passing another array

Comment: I need to addmit it was my big mistake. I created two arrays with objects. So result was good. Please remove this topis, because I don't want to smb. do something wrong after read it. :-D

Comment: @FKa if this answer resolve your problem accept them.. however that was just one of the errors your original code have also errors fixed in my code

Answer (score 0):

You don't update z when you find a younger person:

```
if(a[i].birth>z){
  x = i;
  z = a[i].birth --- so this is bigger year find until now
}
```

Without it you find the last person younger than first person instead of the youngest.

Warning: if in the array there isn't a female this method will return the first element.

P.s. I think that last letter of a name isn't a good parameter to discover if a person is male or female. Perhaps you have to add a data member to your Person object?